# C return and comparation inline

Tags: c, comparison, methods, return-value

I'm just to figure out what does this method do, I know there must be a way to put this line by line, can you help me please?

Thanks

```
int
conditional ( int n, EXPRESSION * * o )
{
  return (evaluateExpression( *o++ )? evaluateExpression( *o ) : evaluateExpression( *++o ) );
}
```

UPDATE: This is the evaluateExpression Code

```
int
evaluateExpresion ( EXPRESSION * e)
{
__asm
{
mov eax,dword ptr [e] 
movsx ecx,byte ptr [eax] 
test ecx,ecx 
jne salto1
mov eax,dword ptr [e] 
mov eax,dword ptr [eax+4] 
jmp final
salto1:
mov esi,esp 
mov eax,dword ptr [e] 
mov ecx,dword ptr [eax+8] 
push ecx  
mov edx,dword ptr [e] 
movsx eax,byte ptr [edx] 
push eax  
mov ecx,dword ptr [e] 
mov edx,dword ptr [ecx+4] 
call edx  
add esp,8
final:
} 
}
```

Comment: Would need the code for the evaluateExpression function.

Comment: Just put the code Blaenk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "ternary expression" used in that long `return` statement has a net effect just like an if/else statement, such as the following:

```
if (evaluateExpression(*o++)) {
  return evaluateExpression(*o);
} else {
  return evaluateExpression(*++o);
}
```

Comment: But, evaluateExpression is not a boolean function, is an integer function. How does this work in this scenario?

Comment: If it `evaluateExpression()` returns 0, it would take the 'false' path.  If it returns anything else it would be 'true'.

Comment: @Randolf: In C, a condition expression (in `if (cond)` or `while (cond)` or `for (...; cond; ...)` or an operand to &&, ||, or !, or  `cond ? ... : ...`) is regarded as FALSE if its value is zero, and TRUE if the value is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

It takes an array of three `EXPRESSION`s and evaluates the first one. If the first one evaluates to a true value, it evaluates the second expression and returns its value. Otherwise it evaluates the third expression and returns its value.